# Python shutil.which not working with wsl.exe

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, shell, shutil

I am trying to use `shutil.which` to check if the Linux Subsystem is installed on Windows 10.

Using the Windows `where` command in Command Prompt, I can see the location of the `wsl.exe` executable.

```
C:\Users\spike>where wsl
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe
```

The above shows that WSL does exist, and is in my system `PATH`.
When I use the `which` function in Python, it says that the executable was not found.

```
print(which("wsl"))  # Returns None
```

Just to make sure that `which` works, I test it on `cmd.exe`.

```
print(which("cmd"))  # Returns "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
```

That works. Well, what if I make a system shell call with the command that *did* work?

```
print(system("where wsl"))  # Returns 1
```

Exit code 1, the command `wsl` was not found.
So I test it on `cmd.exe` again.

```
print(system("where cmd"))  # Returns 0
```

Okay, so that *does* work. What is the problem?

For each Python 3 example assume these imports.

```
from shutil import which
from os import system
```

Why can Python not find `wsl.exe` even though it is proven to exist?

Thanks.

Comment: wsl.exe is only 64-bit, and you're looking in SysWOW64 instead of the real System32 because you're using 32-bit Python.

Comment: @eryksun Ahhh that does explain it. Do you have a way around that? You should post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: In Windows 7+, the real System32 directory is accessible in a 32-bit process as "SysNative". Unfortunately this virtual directory isn't available in a native 64-bit process, so you need to first check whether it exists. For example: `sysnative = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 'SysNative');` `if os.path.exists(sysnative): ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @eryksun, who helped solve this in the comments.

The issue is that I am using 32 bit Python, and `wsl.exe` is only in `C:/Windows/System32`. The problem with this is that Python is looking in `C:/Windows/SysWOW64` for the executable instead.

> `wsl.exe` is only 64-bit, and you're looking in `SysWOW64` instead of the real `System32` because you're using 32-bit Python. – eryksun

Because WSL only supports 64-bit systems, I ended up just running my code with 64-bit Python. However, and alternate solution if you only use Py32 would be to access `SysWOW64` directly, using the system root environment variable and `os.path.join`.

> In Windows 7+, the real `System32` directory is accessible in a 32-bit process as "SysNative". Unfortunately this virtual directory isn't available in a native 64-bit process, so you need to first check whether it exists. For example: `sysnative = os.path.join(os.environ['SystemRoot'], 'SysNative'); if os.path.exists(sysnative): ...`. – eryksun

Answer (score -1):

Now you can install python in 64 bit and everything will work just fine. (Be careful that when the python installer runs, there should be written 64 bit packages and other things as 64 bits [right where the loading bar is])